# I can't link anything on home page in React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React Router Dom v4 and i've got the problem with my home page. All Links doesn't work in home but on others sites it's fine. So this is my route configuration:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Nav />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/tutorials/:id" component={TutorialPost} />
                        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
                        <Route path="/tutorials" component={Tutorials} />
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    </Switch>
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>

        )
    }
}


export default App;
```

I've tried to do simple a href but it doesn't work too.
This is link to my whole repo: https://github.com/javaxd123

This is what the my server return:

```js
[{"createdAt":"2018-04-11T20:47:28Z","updatedAt":"2018-04-11T20:47:28Z","title":"Co z tym NodeJS","imageUrl":"https://www.brainvire.com/wp-content/uploads/The-BIG-Firms-are-using-Node.Js-for-Web-and-Mobile-App.jpg","overview":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi. Aliquam erat ac ipsum. Integer aliquam purus. Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.","content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi. Aliquam erat ac ipsum. Integer aliquam purus. Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.","id":10,"comments":[],"tutorialCategory":{"name":"NodeJS","color":"#8ed100","id":4,"tutorialSet":[]}},{"createdAt":"2018-04-11T15:41:54Z","updatedAt":"2018-04-11T15:41:54Z","title":"Co z tym NodeJS","imageUrl":"https://www.brainvire.com/wp-content/uploads/The-BIG-Firms-are-using-Node.Js-for-Web-and-Mobile-App.jpg","overview":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi. Aliquam erat ac ipsum. Integer aliquam purus. Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.","content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi. Aliquam erat ac ipsum. Integer aliquam purus. Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.","id":9,"comments":[],"tutorialCategory":{"name":"NodeJS","color":"#8ed100","id":3,"tutorialSet":[]}},{"createdAt":"2018-04-10T18:33:48Z","updatedAt":"2018-04-10T18:33:48Z","title":"Co z tym NodeJS","imageUrl":"https://www.brainvire.com/wp-content/uploads/The-BIG-Firms-are-using-Node.Js-for-Web-and-Mobile-App.jpg","overview":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi. Aliquam erat ac ipsum. Integer aliquam purus. Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.","content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi. Aliquam erat ac ipsum. Integer aliquam purus. Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.","id":8,"comments":[],"tutorialCategory":{"name":"NodeJS","color":"#8ed100","id":2,"tutorialSet":[]}},{"createdAt":"2018-04-10T18:12:27Z","updatedAt":"2018-04-10T18:12:27Z","title":"Java, i co dalej?","imageUrl":"https://ocs-pl.oktawave.com/v1/AUTH_2887234e-384a-4873-8bc5-405211db13a2/spidersweb/2014/08/Java.png","overview":"Na pewno część z was nie ma pomysłu na to co zrobić po opanowaniu podstaw Java. W tym wpisie chciałbym wam przybliżyć jak całe to środowisko wygląda na dzień obecny. Będzie również dużo przemyśleń na temat innych języków takich jak np. JavaScript z bogatym środowiskiem nodejs.","content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi. Aliquam erat ac ipsum. Integer aliquam purus. Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.","id":7,"comments":[],"tutorialCategory":{"name":"Java","color":"#69a9e0","id":1,"tutorialSet":[]}},{"createdAt":"2018-04-09T07:33:20Z","updatedAt":"2018-04-09T07:33:20Z","title":"Java, i co dalej?","imageUrl":"https://ocs-pl.oktawave.com/v1/AUTH_2887234e-384a-4873-8bc5-405211db13a2/spidersweb/2014/08/Java.png","overview":"Na pewno część z was nie ma pomysłu na to co zrobić po opanowaniu podstaw Java. W tym wpisie chciałbym wam przybliżyć jak całe to środowisko wygląda na dzień obecny. Będzie również dużo przemyśleń na temat innych języków takich jak np. JavaScript z bogatym środowiskiem nodejs.","content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi. Aliquam erat ac ipsum. Integer aliquam purus. Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.","id":6,"comments":[],"tutorialCategory":{"name":"Java","color":"#69a9e0","id":1,"tutorialSet":[]}},{"createdAt":"2018-04-09T07:04:59Z","updatedAt":"2018-04-09T07:04:59Z","title":"Java, i co dalej?","imageUrl":"https://ocs-pl.oktawave.com/v1/AUTH_2887234e-384a-4873-8bc5-405211db13a2/spidersweb/2014/08/Java.png","overview":"Na pewno część z was nie ma pomysłu na to co zrobić po opanowaniu podstaw Java. W tym wpisie chciałbym wam przybliżyć jak całe to środowisko wygląda na dzień obecny. Będzie również dużo przemyśleń na temat innych języków takich jak np. JavaScript z bogatym środowiskiem nodejs.","content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi. Aliquam erat ac ipsum. Integer aliquam purus. Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.","id":5,"comments":[],"tutorialCategory":{"name":"Java","color":"#69a9e0","id":1,"tutorialSet":[]}}]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze5bU.png)

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? Is there an error?

Comment: If i click on the link nothing happened

Comment: does the link in the browser get updated?

Comment: where that files have those links ?

Comment: in render method

Comment: could you try this: `connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchHomeTutorials, fetchHomeBlogPosts }, null, { pure: false })(Home);` ?

Comment: it still doesn't work :(

Comment: In the tutorial.js all working fine

Comment: but i don't know why on home page doesn't work, it look the same like in tutorial

Comment: Which browser do you use? I clone your project, all url work fine from all pages.

Comment: does browser URL get updated when you click link?

Comment: Mozzilla Firefox

Comment: No The browser doesn't update the URL

Comment: Okay can you edit your anser to paste json that returned by your server?

Comment: Last question, is your cursor pointer when your mouse over links?

Comment: No, nothing, i've tried to click, when i hover  links are not underline

Comment: 1 min i write an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is only styling problem. You set up `z-index: -2` to your `.content-wrapper` for make your navbar to see. But all content in this container not clickable. Set `z-index: 5` to `.content-wrapper` in stylesheets, and set `z-index: 20` to `.navbar` and all links will be clickable.